# Advantages of Windows API for C++ GUI Programming

Tags: c++, windows

I started C++ programming not long before and I want to learn GUI programming in C++. I looked at windows programming and the syntax looks really difficult. So my question is, should I use windows api at all? If so, what are the advantages of windows api over a toolkit like Qt or Direct2D?

Comment: All toolkits have an advantage - and some disadvantages.  The disadvantage might be that you can't do all the things you can do with the lower level api.  Are you sure Qt and Direct2D support all the things you want to do in your program?  It's the same question as "assembly looks harder than C - what is the advantage of using assembly over a higher level language like C?"

Comment: This is way too broad. Btw don't learn by syntax. GUI is not about syntax. it is about design and <captainobvious>user-software interaction</captainobvious>

Answer (score 2):

It somewhat depends what sort of application you are trying to build. Most frameworks provide a level of abstraction over the Windows API but do so at the cost of flexibility. You should try and pick a framework that's designed to build the sort of application that you are trying to build.

For building Windows client applications then the Windows API (I assume you mean the Win32 API) will do the job but is very low level. The advantage is it gives you a great deal of control and also forces you to learn how a Windows application really works. For a lot of people these aren't always positives.

If you are trying to create a more graphically rich application then Direct2D gives you this but also means that you have to learn COM and some would say this API is also quite complex.

If you are just learning C++ and want to build simple graphical applications then I would recommend checking out [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/gallery/). It's perfectly possible to build simple graphically rich applications and games in a few hundred lines of C++. Here's an example of the [Conway's Game of Life written in a couple of hundred lines](https://github.com/AdeMiller/CinderExamples).

Qt is also an option but I've not used it. Again it depends on you goal. For example one of Qt's features is cross platform portability, which may, or may not be important if you are just starting out with C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just creating some projects for your own learning, then I would suggest that you create some GUI using Windows API without any framework. This will help you learn the internals on how things work (messaging, etc).

But to make any real world project you must choose existing framework (MFC, Qt etc) so that you can save a lot of time. You will understand the framework better if you create some GUI projects with plain Windows API SDK.

If you platform is only Windows, then you can in fact develop faster using .Net Framework. Of course there is also Xamarin that will allow you to write in C# for cross platform.

So what you choose depends on your goals.

Answer (score 1):

With WinAPI you can use **all** Windows GUI features, controls, styles, respond to some rarely used messages etc.

It's easier to achieve native Windows look&feel.

Higher-lever GUI libraries, especially multiplatform ones, are usually "least common denominator", limited in many ways, with some controls (e.g. dialogs) reinvented just for the sake of it. You can patch your code with WinAPI calls, but that quickly turns into spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

For one, tools like Qt, OGRE, OSG, OpenGL etc are cross-platform. So you won't be stuck with using your program only on Windows.

If by windows API you meant VC++ with WM_PAINT etc, then it's worth learning it only for the sake of knowledge about how Windows works. The parts about dirty rectangles etc will intrigue you.

Comment: _it's worth learning it only for the sake of knowledge about how Windows works_ As someone who maintains an app built almost entirely with Windows APIs, I would disagree. There's a great deal of power and control that are accessible when you're working directly with the OS APIs. You sacrifice some ease-of-use, but the raw power is worth it imho. (Although of course it depends on your situation: my app is a system utility designed specifically for Windows, and I'll never need to port it to another OS. YMMV.)

Comment: @computerfreaker : I agree with what you mention, but my answer was just focused on the OP's decision of what to do for GUI programming. I'm saying he'd be better off with something like Qt or OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

"I started C++ programming not long before.." - so I would advise to start with well-documented library such as QT. You'll have much to learn in C++ itself and to learn WinAPI at the same time will be twice (or more) difficult.

The answer in general depends on the requirements, and if you want to learn "GUI programming in C++" I'd say it means QT (or some other library/framework). I do not know any rich GUI projects now which are written on pure WinAPI (what for?). (If smb knows, please put a link here.)

But you can ask yourself another question - you want to learn C++ or GUI programming? :)